# Showing Column wise data

Tags: mysql

I have a data in my database

```
userid    module      course     total
  8      Biophysics     A          117
  8      BioPhysics     B           74
  8      BioPhysics     C          135
```

I need the output like

```
userid      module       Courses        grade   
 8        BioPhysics    Course A: 117    250
                        Course B: 134  
                        Course C: 35
```

Comment: This is called a `PIVOT`, which is not possible in MySQL, but you can emulate it if you know beforehand how many columns you need (e.g. is the range of `course` only A-C?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is called "`PIVOT`ing" row data into separate columns, and it is a feature that is not supported by MySQL, but what you *can* do is ***fake*** it if you know beforehand the range of data you want to pivot into columns.

---

### You have a couple of options:

Your example has **A**, **B**, and **C** for `course` per `userid -> module` combination. Assuming the values in `course` can only be **A**, **B**, or **C**: you can do a *conditional aggregation* for each value like so:

```
  SELECT userid,
         module,
         MAX(CASE course WHEN 'A' THEN total END) AS A,
         MAX(CASE course WHEN 'B' THEN total END) AS B,
         MAX(CASE course WHEN 'C' THEN total END) AS C,
         SUM(total) AS grade
    FROM tbl
GROUP BY userid, 
         module
```

You can add as many `CASE` aggregations as you need (for **D**, **E**, **F**, etc.). Keep in mind some `userid -> module` combinations may have `NULL` for some of the columns if, for instance, it did not contain a row with `C` for `course`.

But if you ***do not*** know the range of values beforehand (and perhaps there could be hundreds of different values for `course`, you can still get all of the data onto one row, but it wouldn't be in separate columns - it would actually be one concatenated string in a single column. This is accomplished by using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
  SELECT userid,
         module,
         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(course, ': ', total) SEPARATOR ' / ') AS coursetotals,
         SUM(total) AS grade
    FROM tbl
GROUP BY userid,
         module
```

And what this would do is output something like:

```
userid  |  module      |  coursetotals             |  grade
-------------------------------------------------------------
8       |  BioPhysics  |  A: 117 / B: 74 / C: 135  |  326
```

---

### Here is a [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/068de/2/0) for both options

---

**Edit:** As per your comments and edited, here is the new solution:

```
SELECT 
    a.userid, 
    a.module, 
    CONCAT('Course ', course, ': ', total) AS Courses, 
    b.grade
FROM
    tbl a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, module, SUM(total) AS grade
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY userid, module
) b ON a.userid = b.userid AND a.module = b.module
```

Comment: Hi Zane, can we pullout the data for coursetotals              A:117 and next line B:74 and next line C:135

Comment: @ronquiq What do you mean? Do you want those values on their own row?

Comment: Zane Bien - Can you please suggest me to display the courses in order like how I need the output above

Comment: @ronquiq, sure, just one thing... `117 + 74 + 135 != 250`? Or is that just an example?

Comment: Zane Bien - Can you give any solution for my question " Insert data with submit button - PHP,MySQL" posted recently