# Mysql Query to show the results column wise using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table like below....

```
----------------------------------
|     FeeName      | TotalAmount |
----------------------------------
|    Fee 1         |      100.00 |
|    Fee 2         |      350.00 |
|    Fee 3         |      200.00 |
----------------------------------
```

I want to show the result like below.

```
------------------------------------------
|   Fee 1  |  Fee 2  |  Fee 3  |  Total  |
------------------------------------------
|   100.00 |  350.00 |  200.00 |  650.00 |
------------------------------------------
```

Please Note that, the `FeeName` are dynamic. May be it should show another `Fee 4` or `Fee 5` or not.

How could I do that ?

I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481171/showing-column-wise-data), but it is showing the static columns.

Is it possible to get the output in a query?

I use VB.NET for my application.

Comment: Ideally you would not do this in the query, but in the processing logic afterwards. But if you insist on doing it directly in the query: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+pivot+table

Comment: you want to show the results how? on a webpage? in your SQL editor?

Comment: Yes. Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: You need to use store procedure to customize output

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I want to show means I want to get the output. Thanks

Comment: @Raj No, it doesn't mean that,  because the information is the same in both results in your question, except for the grand total, which is easily obtained with `SUM()`.   So you really are asking about presentation.

Comment: @Raj no I get that :) I mean where are you outputting to? To a webpage or is it just for your own preference to view the data in your SQL editor?

Comment: Basically I use .NET. I want to show the output in a report.

Comment: @Raj then you'll want to restructure your question - it is much better to use (php haha jokes aside now) your language of choice to process and output the data in preferred format. Using MYSQL to do it would be a bad idea and bad practice

Comment: I've modified my question.